# How to prevent snapping in regular to fix-to-top navbar transition?

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-experience

I have manage to design a navbar. Then after I used jQuery to fix it to the top after user has scrolled certain amount to page. Run it to see the effect. I have some problems with it. See below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".nav");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.container {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 520px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.logo-content p {
 line-height: 7rem;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.25rem 0 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(76, 85, 92, 0.7);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1rem calc(1rem - 5px);
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 146, 196, .2);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0, 183, 245);
}
.sub-menu a {
    padding-left: .5rem;
    padding-right: .5rem;
}
.sub-menu i {
    padding-right: .5rem;
}


.sub-menu-parent {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    visiblity: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-2em);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0, visibility 0 linear .3s, z-index 0 linear .01s;
    background: #4c555c;
}
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
    visiblity: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  top: 0;
 background-color: rgb(76, 85, 92) !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-content">
    <p> Blank Space </p>
  </div>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu-parent">
      <a href="/tutorial">Videos</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Tutorials </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-support"></i>Quick Tips </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-film"></i>Films </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>Music Videos </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Extras </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   <!--img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/L9xPDrp.png" width="30px" height="30px"-->
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia sit corrupti magnam? Ullam animi tempore enim soluta. Velit temporibus, voluptate voluptas itaque ab a quos dolore corporis cumque fuga. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere alias labore, corrupti dolore eveniet. Ullam veniam in inventore quo, voluptas nihil similique, ab excepturi ad autem blanditiis assumenda tenetur, tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias earum quos nulla perferendis, voluptate animi libero, soluta officia ipsa voluptatibus vel. Maxime tempora placeat autem, nostrum sequi molestiae delectus nulla.</p>
    <p>Nam asperiores illo repudiandae voluptatum nostrum. Sapiente ad ipsa quod nulla repellat quo doloremque dignissimos inventore voluptas, deleniti aliquam cum magni repudiandae vitae, a corporis quam voluptates nemo vel. Ipsum!</p>
    <p>Ad, nulla modi ipsum. Similique error pariatur, quis facere fugit aliquid incidunt repellendus voluptate harum earum velit a non voluptatum id suscipit, maxime dicta quas tenetur rem ipsam consequuntur corrupti?</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

When point where navbar is sticking to top, you might be able to see that half content of the first `<p>` is almost covered during the snap.

This is unexpected behavior. I want to get rid of this. Flow should be smooth, otherwise it can affect user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-top` as soon as you stick the navbar to top.

Add this condition into your JS code:

```
if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
  s.addClass("stick");
  $('.container').css('padding-top', '90px'); /* Give padding when it sticks to top */
} else {
  s.removeClass("stick"); 
  $('.container').css('padding-top', '0'); /* Remove padding when it again comes back to place */
}
```

Because as soon as the `navbar` sticks to the top, the original place where it was earlier, gets `0` (before it was taking some space for ex. navbar-height = 48px + 42px [approx.]). So now the content shifts upwards to about 90px. So if we give a `padding-top: 90px` to `.container` it adjusts its space and comes a 90px downwards. Its like the navbar is still there upwards the `.container`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".nav");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
            $('.container').css('padding-top', '90px');
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
            $('.container').css('padding-top', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.container {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 520px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.logo-content p {
 line-height: 7rem;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.25rem 0 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(76, 85, 92, 0.7);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1rem calc(1rem - 5px);
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 146, 196, .2);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0, 183, 245);
}
.sub-menu a {
    padding-left: .5rem;
    padding-right: .5rem;
}
.sub-menu i {
    padding-right: .5rem;
}


.sub-menu-parent {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    visiblity: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-2em);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0, visibility 0 linear .3s, z-index 0 linear .01s;
    background: #4c555c;
}
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
    visiblity: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  top: 0;
 background-color: rgb(76, 85, 92) !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-content">
    <p> Blank Space </p>
  </div>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu-parent">
      <a href="/tutorial">Videos</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Tutorials </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-support"></i>Quick Tips </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-film"></i>Films </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>Music Videos </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Extras </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   <!--img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/L9xPDrp.png" width="30px" height="30px"-->
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia sit corrupti magnam? Ullam animi tempore enim soluta. Velit temporibus, voluptate voluptas itaque ab a quos dolore corporis cumque fuga. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere alias labore, corrupti dolore eveniet. Ullam veniam in inventore quo, voluptas nihil similique, ab excepturi ad autem blanditiis assumenda tenetur, tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias earum quos nulla perferendis, voluptate animi libero, soluta officia ipsa voluptatibus vel. Maxime tempora placeat autem, nostrum sequi molestiae delectus nulla.</p>
    <p>Nam asperiores illo repudiandae voluptatum nostrum. Sapiente ad ipsa quod nulla repellat quo doloremque dignissimos inventore voluptas, deleniti aliquam cum magni repudiandae vitae, a corporis quam voluptates nemo vel. Ipsum!</p>
    <p>Ad, nulla modi ipsum. Similique error pariatur, quis facere fugit aliquid incidunt repellendus voluptate harum earum velit a non voluptatum id suscipit, maxime dicta quas tenetur rem ipsam consequuntur corrupti?</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain a bit? From where did the value 90px come from?

Comment: @SantoshKumar As soon as the `navbar` sticks to the top, the original place where it was earlier, gets `0` (before it was taking some space for ex. navbar-height = 48px + 42px [approx.]). So now the content shifts upwards to about 90px. So if we give a `padding-top: 90px` to `.container` it adjusts its space and comes a 90px downwards. Its like the navbar is still there upwards the `.container`. Hope you understand this.

Comment: This comment should be part of the answer.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Sure I'm adding it.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Hope this solution works for you. If you still didn't understand you can let me know the main problem you are getting, Or else you can accept this answer (if this worked). Thanks!

Comment: It isn't working live, temporary address http://www.ajneffects.com/mainhome. No matter what input I provide to the padding-top, it still behaves that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128114/discussion-between-saurav-rastogi-and-santosh-kumar).

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".nav");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.container {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 520px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.logo-content p {
 line-height: 7rem;
}
nav {
min-height: 50px;
 }

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.25rem 0 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(76, 85, 92, 0.7);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 7px 12px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1rem calc(1rem - 5px);
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 146, 196, .2);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0, 183, 245);
}
.sub-menu a {
    padding-left: .5rem;
    padding-right: .5rem;
}
.sub-menu i {
    padding-right: .5rem;
}


.sub-menu-parent {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    visiblity: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-2em);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0, visibility 0 linear .3s, z-index 0 linear .01s;
    background: #4c555c;
}
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
    visiblity: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  top: 0;
 background-color: rgb(76, 85, 92) !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-content">
    <p> Blank Space </p>
  </div>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu-parent">
      <a href="/tutorial">Videos</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Tutorials </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-support"></i>Quick Tips </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-film"></i>Films </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>Music Videos </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Extras </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   <!--img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/L9xPDrp.png" width="30px" height="30px"-->
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia sit corrupti magnam? Ullam animi tempore enim soluta. Velit temporibus, voluptate voluptas itaque ab a quos dolore corporis cumque fuga. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere alias labore, corrupti dolore eveniet. Ullam veniam in inventore quo, voluptas nihil similique, ab excepturi ad autem blanditiis assumenda tenetur, tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias earum quos nulla perferendis, voluptate animi libero, soluta officia ipsa voluptatibus vel. Maxime tempora placeat autem, nostrum sequi molestiae delectus nulla.</p>
    <p>Nam asperiores illo repudiandae voluptatum nostrum. Sapiente ad ipsa quod nulla repellat quo doloremque dignissimos inventore voluptas, deleniti aliquam cum magni repudiandae vitae, a corporis quam voluptates nemo vel. Ipsum!</p>
    <p>Ad, nulla modi ipsum. Similique error pariatur, quis facere fugit aliquid incidunt repellendus voluptate harum earum velit a non voluptatum id suscipit, maxime dicta quas tenetur rem ipsam consequuntur corrupti?</p>
</div>
  </div>
```